# How to use clarifai to detect the position of an object in an image in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, object-detection, clarifai

I am building an android and ios applicaion using xamarin that should detects the object that I click on in an image . I have succeeded in detecting if a specific object is in the image or not using https://portal.clarifai.com , by training some models and predict the probability of their presence in the image .

Now I am trying to detect the position of this object (to predict after that what is the object that I am clicking on )

can anyone help me please ?

```
var client = new ClarifaiClient(my-api-key);

var response = await client.Predict<Concept>(my-concept-id, 
                new ClarifaiFileImage(ReadFully((file.GetStream())))).ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var concept in response.Get().Data)
            {
                s += concept.Name + " : " + concept.Value + "\n";
            }
```

Comment: just browsing their API docs it doesn't appear that this is data they supply.  I'd suggest you contact their dev support and ask, there doesn't appear to be much activity for that tag on SO

Comment: Are you looking for the position of an object inside the picture? Or are you looking for the position of that picture on the screen?

Comment: @Saamer the position of the object inside the picture

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the position of the object inside a picture with Clarifai, but you can with Microsoft's Custom Vision AI.
As you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/csharp-tutorial-od), it gives you the exact coordinates for you to do that.